# How can I search the specific word in VS Code that doesn't have extra characters before or after

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example:

1. Oldcoin23
2. coin

In this above two words i only need to get the second word 'coin'

I searched the word 'coin' in Vs Code by pressing Ctrl + Shift + F. But I am getting both word as a result. I.e., 'coin' and 'Oldcoin23'.

How can I get only the word of 'coin' and not any other word that contain the word 'coin' inside.

Answer (score 0):

Enable regex mode for the find widget (use the [image]/[image] button or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>), and then put `\bcoin\b` in the search input. In Regex, `\b` means to match word boundaries. Quoting regex101.com:

> `\b`
> Matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w (in either order). It cannot be used to separate non words from words.

Answer (score -1):

Use this regex search pattern: `(?<!\w)coin(?!\w)`. To use this, you need to check the regex box in the find menu.

[image]

The way the regex works is that it uses a negative lookbehind `(?<!\w)` to discard any results that have a word character before them, and a negative lookahead to discard any results that have a word character in front of them, `(?!\w)`, and searches for the word `coin`.